# name 'Actual365NoLeap' is not defined even after import

Tags: python, import, quantlib

```py
from QuantLib import *

DC = [Actual360(), Actual365Fixed(), Actual365NoLeap(), ActualActual(), Business252(), OneDayCounter(), Thirty360()]
```

This gives an error only for `Actual365NoLeap()` method and not the others.

Comment: This is the error i get: Error while executing callback registered on port(s) ['input']: name 'Actual365NoLeap' is not defined [line 114]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Actual365NoLeap` as a class on its own was deprecated in version 1.11 and removed in version 1.16.  You can use `Actual365Fixed(Actual365Fixed.NoLeap)` instead.